# Regex performance issue when trying to get snippet of match from long text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a matching word along with some words ahead of and after it (at most 5) with the below regex:

```js
const start = Date.now();
console.log("There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).".match(/(\S*\s*){0,5}lorem(\s*\S*){0,5}/giu));

console.log(Date.now() - start);
```

This though seems to be very slow, and it takes in the hundreds of milliseconds. Is there something I am missing and could this be improved in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes, replace `(\S*\s*){0,5}` with `(?:\S+\s+){0,5}` and `(\s*\S*){0,5}` with `(?:\s+\S+){0,5}`.

Comment: Also use [console time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the OP wants to take up to 5 words ahead and behind `lorem`. So if we change `\S*\s*` to `\S+\s+` the regex is faster like 100x times. Also the OP's regex fails with single quotes:

```
and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web
```

My regex failed too so added `\S*lorem\S*`.

Also we could omit capturing the words.

So the final regex:

```
/(?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S*lorem\S*(?:\s+\S+){0,5}/giu
```

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="100">

const str = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). and lorem again.";

// @benchmark original
str.match(/(\S*\s*){0,5}lorem(\s*\S*){0,5}/giu)

// @benchmark Alexander
str.match(/(?:\S+\s+){0,5}\S*lorem\S*(?:\s+\S+){0,5}/giu)

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. The fix for the single quotes (which in my case was a dash after the word to match, like `lorem-s`), was what I was looking now after the improvement suggestion update.